# What is the Derivative of x^x

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I was browsing through my old textbook and I found this problem:

Find Derivative of $ x^x$

**My work** :

Haven't got a clue yet, where to start?

Comment: huge hint: $\ x^x=e^{\ln(x^x)}$

Comment: Set $y = x^{x}$, take logs of both sides, differentiate..

Comment: Thanks @Mosk , really helped

Answer (score 3):

You start by writing $x^x = e^{x\ln x}$.  I hope you can progress from there by the chain rule, product rule, et cetera.

Comment: is it ln or is it log?

Comment: I'm using $x = e^{\ln x}$, so it's the former.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = x^x = e^{\ln (x^x)} = e^{x\ln(x)}$

Now we can calculate the derivate of $e^{x\ln(x)}$.

So we get $f^{\prime}(x) = e^{x\ln(x)}\left(\ln(x) + \frac{x}{x}\right) = (\ln(x) + 1)x^x$.

Do you see why? I used the product rule and the fact that $x^x = e^{\ln(x^x)} = e^{x\ln(x)}$.

I hope this helps.